# jQuery load access main javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue with a prototype where I load pages through

```
$("#tab").load(/a/relative/pad);
```

The problem is that I'm unable to access the Javascript in the original environment, is there a way to get around this?

Comment: What does "access the Javascript in the original environment" mean?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by _"access the Javascript in the original environment?"_

Comment: So I have a page A in which I load content through the $(..).load() function (page B). If there is a javascript function call in page B to a function declared in page A, this won't get called. I hope this makes the question more clear?

Comment: Please edit your question not shove extra info in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript in the content of a loaded document does not get fired.  What you can do is have a the callback of load fire the Javascript method you need.

If the function you need call after the load is dependent on the data you get back from the load, you can get the parameters you need during the callback of load.

```
$("#tab").load("/a/relative/pad", function(){
    //find your parameter
    var parameter = $("#parameter", "#tab");
    //call your callback method
    callback(parameter);
});
```

If no extra parameters are needed to make the callback:

```
$("#tab").load("/a/relative/pad", function(){
    //call your callback method
    callback(parameter);
});
```

Or if you prefer to not have an anonymous function:

```
$("#tab").load("/a/relative/pad", callback);
```

In all these cases `callback` is a function that exists on page A

Alternatively, while this is not in best practices, you could have a hidden block of text on page B that is actually a script block and you could call `ecal()` on that script.

```
$("#tab").load("/a/relative/pad", function(){
    //get the block of script you need to run
    var scriptToRun = $("#hiddenScriptBlock", "#tab");
    //run the script
    eval(scriptToRun);
});
```

Comment: I'm not quite certain about what you mean, does this make it possible to make a call from page B to page A?

Comment: No.  The call is still coming from page A, but that call is not made until page B is loaded.  Can you provide more details on what it is exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your response. For the moment I can't give an exact example of what I'm trying to achieve but I'll do my best to describe it. 
I have a jCarousel in which I load dynamic content (pages I generate). To populate the 'tabs' in this carousel I use the $().load() function, which gives the adressed problems. Is there another way to load HTML on runtime which will bypass this problem?

Comment: If page B is calling a method from page A after B loads onto A, why not just have page A make that same call when B is loaded?  That is what the callback function is doing in my answer.  (I am adding a second example)

Comment: No the issue is not that I want to call a parent function directly after the load() is executed; due to interactions on page B, it could be that after some time I want to call a function from page A.